# Removing Duplicates that aren't identical duplicates

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am trying to weed out "duplicates" (from cmemails.csubject) even though they are not identical in their file naming.  Below are identical files (except for the file name).  How do I get rid of all the duplicate records?  I can't figure out how to compare these emails, let alone remove the duplicates.

```
***ORIGINAL***  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT.MSG
**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 1.MSG 
**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 99.MSG 
**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 401.MS
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, you could try something like this (the first browse shows the four records, the second browse shows only the original).The following example can be run in a command window to show a couple of samples using the DELETE command:

```
Set Deleted On
Create Cursor test (nrec i, cfile c(150))
Insert Into test Values (1,"***ORIGINAL***  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT.MSG")
Insert Into test Values (2,"**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 1.MSG")
Insert Into test Values (3,"**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 99.MSG")
Insert Into test Values (4,"**DUPLICATE **  2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991 -21 OCT 2013 07-00 GMT - 401.MS")
Browse Last
Delete For Left(cfile,14)="**DUPLICATE **"
Browse Last
Recall All
Browse Last
Delete For "2013-10-07 - CHANGEMAN@MICROSOFT.COM - MS DEMAND MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION -  TN049991" $ cfile And Left(cfile,14)<>"***ORIGINAL***"
Browse Last
```